# Как изменить цвет ссылки / Как выделить ссылку цветом

Tags: html, css

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как сделать ссылку в HTML цветной?

Буду благодарна, если на мой вопрос найдется ответ.

Answer (score 8):

```
 <style>
   a:link {
    color: #00d0d0; /* Цвет ссылок */
   }
   a:visited {
    color: #900060; /* Цвет посещенных ссылок */
   }
   a:active {
    color: #f00; /* Цвет активной ссылки */ 
   }
 </style>
```

Корректнее было спросить: "Как изменить цвет ссылок?"

Comment: + a:hover {}

Comment: :) хорошая шутка)) в тему

Answer (score 3):

Вариантов несколько. Первый был показан выше, но у него есть один минус - он будет работать для всех ссылок, которые только есть на странице, где описано CSS свойство "`a`".
Если вам так и надо, то дальше можно не читать. Если желаете узнать второй вариант, то он такой: можно для каждой ссылки прописывать класс, в котором будут храниться стили только для данной ссылки:

```
<style>
.mylink{color:red; font-size:12pt;}
.mylink:hover{color:blue; font-size:16pt;}
</style>
<a class='mylink' href='#'>LINK</a>
```

Comment: Имхо, этот подход — правильный, более поддерживаемый и расширяемый.

Answer (score 0):

**[Псевдокласс :link](http://htmlbook.ru/css/link)**.

> Псевдокласс :link применяется к ссылкам, которые еще не посещались пользователем, и задает для них стилевое оформление.

Answer (score 0):

А ещё лучше создать файл с расширением `.css` и вписывать туда все перечисленные селекторы `a` классы `.class` и идентификаторы `#id`, а в самом файле html указать путь к файлу, например:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
```