# как в классе css установить цвет ссылки, отличный от общего?

Tags: css

имеется класс:

```
.important {
    border: double lightskyblue 0.45rem;
    font-size: 125%;
    color: darkred;
}
```

но свойство color на ссылки не влияет... каким способом можно задать тот же цвет и для ссылки?

Comment: Указать `color: darkred !important;`?

Comment: Приведите код Html

Comment: Связанные: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/94034/256824

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Без адекватного примера html кода это гадание на кофейной гуще, но я попробую. Как я понимаю, у вас ссылка находится внутри класса, поэтому, чтобы переопределить ее, нужно указывать цвет ссылки внутри элемента, а не просто цвет текста этого элемента.

Грубо говоря так:

```
.important a{
    color: darkred;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Советую прочитать - http://htmlbook.ru/content/svoystva-ssylok

```
a:link {color:  darkred } 
a:visited {color:  darkred } 
a:active { color: darkred; }
a:hover {color: darkred; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Что-бы задать св-во ссылке к ней нужно обращаться "на прямую": а { color: darkred; }

Comment: Конкретно этим, вы обратитесь ко всем элементам `a`

Answer (score 0):

Добавьте к ссылке класс *important*:

```
<a href="..." class="important">...</a>
```

Comment: попробуйте искать не сам клас important, a ссылку с класом `a.important{color: darkred;}`