# Помогите решить задачу с footer

Tags: css3, html5

[image: Скрин footer]

Ребят, будьте так добры, подскажите как так оформить ссылки в footer, как на данном изображении.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как изменить цвет ссылки / Как выделить ссылку цветом](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/94034/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%86%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%82-%d1%81%d1%81%d1%8b%d0%bb%d0%ba%d0%b8-%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%81%d1%81%d1%8b%d0%bb%d0%ba%d1%83-%d1%86%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%82%d0%be%d0%bc)

Answer (score 4):

так что ли?

```css
footer{
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  background-color: #202020;
}
footer a, footer span, .links{
  color:#808080;
}
```

```html
<footer>
  <div class="links">
  <a href="#">Служба поддержки</a> | <a href="#">Политика конфиденциальности</a>
  </div>
  <div>
    <span>Позвоните нам 54515151515</span>
  </div>
</footer>
```

Comment: Благодарю)
Я еще совсем начинающий, поэтому много чего не знаю)